# JMS\SecurityExtraBundle complains about permission errors under Fedora 18

Tags: symfony, fedora, selinux

I have just upgraded my development system to Fedora 18-Beta. Just after this, my Symfony 2 projects stopped working, stating that JMSSecurityExtraBundle is trying to run grep, which exits with non-success status code of 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Fedora guys have changed some context defaults for the httpd package. According to `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts`:

```
/var/www(/.*)?/logs(/.*)?   system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
```

they have changed the default context of all files in any directory called `logs` under `/var/www`. As some vendor directories contain `.git` dirs, which eventually contain a directory called `logs`, they will be automatically labeled as `httpd_log_t`.

The solution to change this, is to issue this command:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/var/www(/.*)?/\.git/logs(/.*)?'
```